# read file and get specific contents and echo them (php)

Tags: php, file-io

I have a file (passwords_admin.txt) that contains information like this:

```
# This file is for storing administrative
# .passwords_user in the same directory.
#
# NOTE (Important):
# format: <server type> <keyword>[,<keyword>...] <server name> <login name> <password>      
[<location> [<host> <port>] ]
# The first entry for a given server will be the default user.
# Current keywords:
# livepw - The password change script will change the sa password on this server to the 
new live password
# devpw - The password change script will change the sa password on this server to the 
new dev password
## mysql servers
##
# Do not remove the next line
# ----------- MySQL Instances start here ----------
mysql 1515,dev,devpw,online,ldap_pwd dev-exodus-01 dba_admin B66AF9 166.77.177.241 3306
mysql 1515,dev,devpw,online,ldap_pwd dev-exodus-01 dba_query 83939E 166.77.177.241 3306
mysql 1515,dev,devpw,online,ldap_pwd qa-exodus-01 dba_admin B66AF9 166.77.189.125 3306
mysql 1515,dev,devpw,online,ldap_pwd qa-exodus-01 dba_query 583939E 166.77.189.125 3306
...
...
```

Data is stored in this formate:`format: <server type> <keyword>[,<keyword>...] <server name> <login name> <password> [<location> [<host> <port>] ]`

Now, I want to copy and print hostname and keyword(devpw or livepw) of a specific instance.

For example, for instance dev-exodus-01. I want to print it's hostname which 166.77.177.241 and it's keyword `devpw`. Or Is there any way I can store these values in variables and I can use them later?

I tried this, but obviously it is not working.

```
$file = fopen("passwords_admin.txt", "r");
if (!$file) {
    echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.\n";
    exit;
}
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file, 1024);

    if (preg_match("@devpw(.*)@i", $line, $out)) {
        $title = $out[1];
        echo $title;
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why is it obviously not working? What is the problem when you run it?

Comment: it is not showing anything...no error...nothing...just blank page

Comment: Well, your `echo` is after the `break`, so it's never going to echo anything....

Comment: and according to this code, it will print the whole line matching keyword `devpw`. But I want to store keyword and hostname in variables. so that i can use them later.

Comment: i edited the code with new information. but as I told you. I dont want the whole line. I just want keyword and hostname of a specified instance.

Comment: `explode` on spaces to get the various data, and write them to variables as you parse the file?

Comment: Ok. Got you. But can you show me a simple example of how to do it? or any reference is fine...

Comment: I've added an answer which should help, I hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction:

```
if (preg_match("@devpw(.*)@i", $line)) {
    $data = explode (" ", $line);
    $keywords = $data[1];
    $hostname = $data[5];
}
```

It splits the line into an array, based on your format. The `$hostname` is set to the sixth entry, and `$keywords` are in the second one.

You'll need to do something similar with `$keywords` to get the individual keywords, and you'll need to figure out a way of either just finding the one line from the config file you want, or of storing multiple rows of data - an array of associative arrays might work.

Comment: hey i have got a question. the code you provided is working fine. But i can i avoid comments(`#`)? and is there a way to check two conditions in preg_match?

Comment: What is the definition of a comment? Is it at the start of a line, or can it start anywhere? `preg_match` lets you run a regular expression, which can be as complex as you can make it; you can make your one `preg_match` more complex to check both conditions, or you can call it twice, with different conditions in each

Comment: Yes `#` is at the start of a line.

Comment: I tried this `if (preg_match("@$a(.*)@i", $line)) {
    if (!preg_match("/^$comment/", $line)){
    $data = explode (" ", $line);
    $database = $data[0];
    $keywords = $data[1];
    $servername = $data[2];
    $password = $data[4];
    $hostname = $data[5];
    echo "$database  ";
    echo "$keywords  ";
    echo "$servername  ";
    echo "$hostname  ";
    echo "<br/>";
    }
}
}` `$a` has the string to match and `$comment` contains `#` and it worked. :)